# UICollection View With TableView Error Index Out of Range Why

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have dictionary array [String:[String]] and i want to show collection view inside table view, but when data is loaded it gives error that index is out of bounds in cellForItem of collectionView.
Here is full source code of my UIViewController

```
    import UIKit
     struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [String]!
    } class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    var TestArray = ["Hair": ["1","2","3"],"Nail": ["1","2"],"Makeup":["1","2","3","4"]]
     var Sections:[String] = []
     var objectArray = [Objects]()
    var section = 0
    var nameTest:String = ""
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for (name, path) in TestArray {
       // print("The path to '\(name)' is '\(path)'.")
        var nameTest = name as? String
       // print("value count \(TestArray[name]?.count)")
        Sections.append(nameTest!)
    }
    for (key, value) in TestArray {
        objectArray.append(Objects(sectionName: key, sectionObjects: value))
    }
}
// MARK: - Table view data source
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    print("Table View Number of Secltions \(objectArray.count)")
    return objectArray.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return objectArray[section].sectionName
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Test", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
    // Configure the cell...
section = indexPath.section //cell!.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] cell?.TestCollectionView.delegate = self cell?.TestCollectionView.dataSource = self cell?.TestCollectionView.reloadData()
    return cell!
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 160
}
} extension TableViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource { func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int { print("Collection View Number Of Item in Section (objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count)") return objectArray[section].sectionObjects.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
    cell?.Name.text = objectArray[section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] // here index out of range 
    return cell!
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong approach by initializing section globally, and assigning its value in cellForRow, as cellForRow is called many times, its value changes according to its currently displayed cell.I have made some changes in code please check.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Test", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell

// Configure the cell...

 section = indexPath.section // remove this line
 cell?.TestCollectionView.tag = indexPath.section // add this line
  //cell!.textLabel?.text = objectArray[indexPath.section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] 
cell?.TestCollectionView.delegate = self 
cell?.TestCollectionView.dataSource = self 
cell?.TestCollectionView.reloadData()

return cell!
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
cell?.Name.text = objectArray[section].sectionObjects[indexPath.row] // remove this line
cell?.Name.text = objectArray[collectionView.tag].sectionObjects[indexPath.row]// add this line
return cell!
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectArray[collectionView.tag].sectionObjects.count
}
```

Comment: Same Result index out of range on this line